# JavaScript code throwing error when run on my Apache server, but it runs fine in CodePen

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a language selector for my website, so I created a CodePen and uploaded it to my site, but the dropdown menu is blank and the code doesn't work.
I get this error when I look in the FireBug console while on my website:

SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters

But the line it is referring to has no errors.

Here is the [CodePen version.](https://codepen.io/CookieGames/pen/oMBjBm)

```
No Errors
```

and here is the one on [my website](https://cookiegames.co.uk/cg.html).

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters
```

My Webserver is an Apache server hosted on a Debian system

Comment: show the code, in order to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on *"Analyze JS"* in CodePen, it will also yield the same error, see the screenshot below.

`function resolveMLString(stringToBeResolved: string, mLstrings) {` is not valid JavaScript. You should delete `: string` part.

Or if you wanted to use TypeScript (where types can be specified in function headers), compile your code to JavaScript using `tsc` and include the resulting JS code in your website.

[image]